# hibernate hsql getting error No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I am getting an error in my hsql

```
No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode 
 +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'OrderLocation' {originalText=OrderLocation}
```

My Mapping class like this

```
<class name="core.classes.lab.LabOrder" table="lab_order">

        <id name="Order_ID" type="int" column="labOrder_ID">
            <generator class="increment" /> 
        </id>

        <many-to-one name="TestID" class="core.classes.lab.TestDescription"
            fetch="join">
            <column name="TestID" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>

        <property name="OrderLocation" column="labOrder_Location"
            type="string" />
        <property name="OrderStatus" column="labOrder_Status" type="string" />
        <property name="DueDate" column="labOrder_DueDate" type="java.util.Date" />
        <property name="OrderPriority" column="labOrder_Priority"
            type="int" />
        <property name="OrderRemarks" column="labOrder_Remarks" type="string" />

        <property name="OrderCreateDate" column="labOrder_CreateDate"
            type="java.util.Date" />
        <property name="OrderCreateUser" column="labOrder_CreateUser"
            type="int" />
        <property name="OrderLastUpdate" column="labOrder_LastUpdate"
            type="java.util.Date" />
        <property name="OrderLastUpdateUser" column="labOrder_LastUpdateUser"
            type="int" />
    </class>
```

and my hsql query like this

```
Select e from LabOrder as e,TestDescription as t where e.TestID =t.TestID and t.isSpecimenAvailable = true
```

can anyone tell me why i getting an error like this pls help me thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's **e** doing in `Select e from ....`? 
Try changing it to `e.OrderLocation` or `*`.

Check [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm) for examples.

Comment: thanx i able to fix it by removing select , but now i getting the all the objects now is there a way to remove the 2nd object

Comment: Can you tell me what is the 2nd object? Is this the one -OrderStatus?

Comment: now i am using a query like this "from LabOrder as e,TestDescription as t where e.TestID =t.TestID and t.isSpecimenAvailable = true" and i am getting the all the row details of TestDescription table but i dont need that

Comment: Which fields do you need? You can provide specific fields like so - `select e.OrderLocation, t.TestID ...`, if you like. Thanks!

Comment: i am get  these values and convert them to json since this is a web service so when specify the column names i dont get the column name as the tags so i need to get the column name as well as the values. but when i specify the columns it dont give me the column names but when i use the above comment query i am getting the column names, so what should i do

Comment: I think I'm not able to understand you clearly. But I can guess you want the column names (Objects) and you want to dretrieve their values. Please take a look at this link: http://www.java4s.com/hibernate/part-4-hibernate-query-language-using-hql-select-query/ and this http://emrpms.blogspot.in/2012/06/select-only-few-columns-in-hibernate.html

Answer (score 2):

A problem that took me some time to debug was a query which worked well for Hibernate 3.x and was like this:

```
SELECT a FROM Actor A
```

When I upgraded to Hibernate 4.x I got an error message similar to the one above. The problem was surprisingly the capital A.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the query is properly written such as,

```
select user from User user;
```

Syntax:

```
SELECT <alias_name> FROM <EntityClass> <alias_name>;
```